# Handling Tasks to read HttpRequestMessage in an Azure Function App

Tags: c#, async-await, azure

I am writing an Azure function app to receive a file uploaded through a `multipart/form-data` HTML form. I think the only way to get my uploaded data is by probing the `HttpRequestMessage req` but I can only do this using Async extension methods such as `.ReadAsMultipartAsync()` (it seems)

So I have ended up with this pattern of get-task-and-run-synchronously-if-not-completed, and I am concerned that this might be really wrong:

```
var multipartTask = req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
if (!multipartTask.IsCompleted)
{
    multipartTask.RunSynchronously();
}
stream = multipartTask.Result;
```

I could `await` each call but that would require me to change the signature of the function to make it an `async Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and I don't trust that to work correctly within the Azure Functions environment.

Here is the complete code of my function. This is a prototype so I realise there is also some work to do with refactoring out repeated code into other classes.

```
[FunctionName("Load")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "Load")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    MultipartMemoryStreamProvider stream;
    try
    {
        var multipartTask = req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        if (!multipartTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            multipartTask.RunSynchronously();
        }
        stream = multipartTask.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Posted data was not multipart or read failed");
    }
    string fileContent;
    try
    {
        var httpContent = stream.Contents[0];
        var contentTask = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (!contentTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            contentTask.RunSynchronously();
        }
        fileContent = contentTask.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unable to read file stream");
    }
    try
    {
        WriteGrammar("stegriff", fileContent);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Failed to write grammar");
    }
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Hello world");
}
```